# MYSQL count rows with a specific value in one table and insert into a specific row in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a NAME value. I have another table that has a related NAME value.
I want to count the number of rows from Table1 that have NAME: John Doe,
and update that Count in Table2, under 'count' where that name matches.

How can I write this in MYSQL?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included some information about your structure.  Also, give some background on what you have tried, the errors you get, etc.  You will likely have more luck getting people to help you.  Take a look at this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by preparing the desired value in your insert query like that :

```
INSERT INTO `Table2`(`name`, `count`)
SELECT 'John Doe', COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `Table1`
WHERE `name` = 'John Doe';
```

In this case, the result of the selection will be ['John Doe', ].
and next, the selection result will be inserted in Table2

If you need to update existing record in table2:

```
UPDATE `Table2`
SET `count` = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `Table1` 
    WHERE `name` = 'John Doe'
)
WHERE `name` = 'John Doe';
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I neglected to say I want to update an existing tables value of 'count'

Comment: if you need to update count you can use this query :  `UPDATE `Table2`
SET `count` = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `Table1` 
    WHERE `name` = 'John Doe'
)
WHERE `name` = 'John Doe';`